# How to make GIMP 2.10 titlebar black

Tags: gnome, gimp, 18.10, titlebar

By default, Gimp 2.10.6 in Ubuntu 18.10 uses a dark theme. However, in a vanilla Gnome session using the default Adwaita theme, or with any other light theme, the title bar is light. Is there a way to have Gimp automatically adopt a black title bar when launched?

Comment: The title bar isn't under the control of the app, it is a desktop manager thing. Usually the DM has two colors, one for active and one for inactive windows. perhaps there is a DM somewhere that can force a color on some window/application.

Comment: For sure, "legacy" window bars (in contrast to the Client Side Decorations used by Gnome and other GTK-3 applications), are controlled by the WM, Mutter in the case of Gnome.

Comment: @vanadium can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My new, simpler solution

Another solution is to use [Dark-Headers](https://github.com/catvitalio/dark-headers), a background service will ensure that your software always has a dark title bar.

Follow the installation instructions on [the Github page](https://github.com/catvitalio/dark-headers), and define the list of software in `~/.config/dark-headers.conf`.

Kudos to [@catvitalio](https://github.com/catvitalio) for developing the service.

---

## My original solution

Open Gimp, and run the following command in a terminal:

```sh
xprop -f _GTK_THEME_VARIANT 8u -set _GTK_THEME_VARIANT dark
```

Then click on the Gimp window. Its titlebar will become dark.

Unfortunately you have to do this each and every time you open Gimp. I am sure there must be a way to run this command via a Bash script so that it happens automatically. The following bash script should automate this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
WINTITLE="GNU Image Manipulation Program"
APP="flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP"
$APP &
until [ -n "$(wmctrl -l | grep "$WINTITLE")" ] ; do : ; done 
WINID=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$WINTITLE" | awk '//{print $1}')
xprop -f _GTK_THEME_VARIANT 8u -set _GTK_THEME_VARIANT dark -id $WINID
```

You would then just modify your menu entry to launch the bash script, rather than directly launching Gimp.

You can use the [MenuLibre](https://bluesabre.org/menulibre/) tool to modify menu entries easily.

Source: https://eischmann.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/dark-title-bars-for-apps-with-dark-ui/